# Shared login in a Ruby on Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, authentication

Certain sites (primarily relationship sites) like Avocado.io offer a login where you sign up as a couple with your own email addresses but with the same password. In database terms is this considered one user? I am wondering how you would do this in Rails.

The database part is where I am getting a bit confused, not how to build a login. So lets say that I login to the site, how does it know that it was me that logged in and not my significant other?

I can see doing this as a relational database where you have two users joined by the relationship, but the shared password makes me feel like they are a single user instance. So how would I display my name in the navigation bar for example.

Comment: I do not know avocado.io, but if I understand correctly it just creates two users in one go, right? Signing up as a couple, two email-adresses, and one password? In the database I would just create two users, each with their own password, which just happens to be the same :) You still login with your own email address right? Or is it one user, one username (for the couple), with two email-addresses?

Comment: It's two emails with the same password. A relational type database is what makes sense to me and seems like what you are saying as well. I guess I didn't think about that, you can just create two users who happen to have the same password